# How to use MERGE instead of INSERT INTO and UPDATE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, insert, merge

I have a stored procedure that contains the following.

This is used to check if a certain ID exists. If no, then it inserts a new record into the table, if yes, then it updates the existing one.

The procedure works as intended but I was wondering if I could achieve the same using MERGE to improve the code a little. How can I do this using MERGE and are there any advantages / disadvantages compared to what I have?

```
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT      * 
        FROM        MOC_Comments 
        WHERE       commentID = @commentID
    )
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO MOC_Comments
            (
                    parentID, 
                    comment
            )
            SELECT  @parentID,
                    @comment
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN

            UPDATE  MOC_Comments
            SET     parentID = @parentID,
                    comment = @comment
        END 
END
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server Merge statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142954/sql-server-merge-statement)

Comment: How to `MERGE` "best practice" you can find here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879317(v=sql.105).aspx   Also you can find interesting this post about performance: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2651/comparing-performance-for-the-merge-statement-to-select-insert-update-or-delete/

Comment: Thanks, All - I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the basic merge statement to do what you are looking for:

I updated the "update" portion of the merge to show how you can update a record without passing in every single parameter in a "set" method. The coalesce checks the source (input parameter) first, if null, it will use the existing value in the record. This allows you to write a set method with all nullable parameters, one for every column in a table or structure (except for the unique constraint or primary key), and only pass in the parameters for which you want to update the corresponding record column.

```
merge into [dbo].[moc_comments] as target
using (values(@parentid
  , @comment
  , @commentid)) as source ([parentid], [comment], [commentid])
on target.[commentid] = source.[commentid]
when matched then
  update set target.[parentid] = coalesce(source.[parentid], target.[parentid])
         , target.[comment] = coalesce(source.[comment], target.[comment])
when not matched by target then
  insert ([parentid]
      , [comment]
      , [commentid])
  values ([parentid]
      , [comment]
      , [commentid]);
```